# Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda

Tags: haskell

I am getting Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda. I am not sure of the cause yet. Please anyone how to fix it. The code is below:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
time_spent h1 h2 = max (abs (fst h1 - fst h2)) (abs (snd h1 - snd h2))
meeting_point xs = foldl' (find_min_time) maxBound xs
where
    time_to_point p = foldl' (\tacc p' -> tacc + (time_spent p p')) 0 xs
    find_min_time min_time p = let x = time_to_point p in if x < min_time  then x else min_time

main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  points <- fmap (map (\[x,y] -> (x,y)) . map (map (read :: String->Int)) . map words . lines) getContents
  putStrLn $ show $ meeting_point points
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the lambda with the non-exhaustive patterns: `\[x,y] -> (x,y)`.

The non-exhaustive pattern is because the argument you've specified, `[x,y]` doesn't match any possible list - it only matches lists with precisely two elements.

I would suggest replacing it with a separate function with an error case to print out the unexpected data in an error message so you can debug further, e.g.:

```
f [x,y] = (x, y)
f l = error $ "Unexpected list: " ++ show l

...
points <- fmap (map f . map ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. (The judge input contains empty line that caused the problem i guess. Probably i need to read the next 'n' lines (which contain pairs of integers) and turn it into a list of points.)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @GaneshSittampalam's answer, you could also do this with more graceful error handling using the `Maybe` monad, the `mapM` function from `Control.Monad`, and `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`.  I would also recommend refactoring your code so that the parsing is its own function, it makes your `main` function much cleaner and easier to debug.

```
import Control.Monad (mapM)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

toPoint :: [a] -> Maybe (a, a)
toPoint [x, y] = Just (x, y)
toPoint _      = Nothing
```

This is just a simple pattern matching function that returns `Nothing` if it gets a list with length not 2.  Otherwise it turns it into a 2-tuple and wraps it in `Just`.

```
parseData :: String -> Maybe [(Int, Int)]
parseData text = do
    -- returns Nothing if a non-Int is encountered
    values <- mapM (mapM readMaybe . words) . lines $ text
    -- returns Nothing if a line doesn't have exactly 2 values
    mapM toPoint values
```

Your parsing can actually be simplified significantly by using `mapM` and `readMaybe`.  The type of `readMaybe` is `Read a => String -> Maybe a`, and in this case since we've specified the type of `parseData` to return `Maybe [(Int, Int)]`, the compiler can infer that `readMaybe` should have the local type of `String -> Maybe Int`.  We still use `lines` and `words` in the same way, but now since we use `mapM` the type of the right hand side of the `<-` is `Maybe [[Int]]`, so the type of `values` is `[[Int]]`.  What `mapM` also does for us is if any of those actions fails, the overall computation exits early with `Nothing`.  Then we simply use `mapM toPoint` to convert `values` into a list of points, but also with the failure mechanism built in.  We actually could use the more general signature of `parseData :: Read a => String -> Maybe [(a, a)]`, but it isn't necessary.

```
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  points <- fmap parseData getContents
  case points of
      Just ps -> print $ meeting_point ps
      Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid data!"
```

Now we just use `fmap parseData` on `getContents`, making `points` have the type `Maybe [(Int, Int)]`.  Finally, we pattern match on `points` to print out the result of the `meeting_point` computation or print a helpful message if something went wrong.

---

If you wanted even better error handling, you could leverage the `Either` monad in a similar fashion:

```
toPoint :: [a] -> Either String (a, a)
toPoint [x, y] = Right (x, y)
toPoint _      = Left "Invalid number of points"

readEither :: Read a => String -> Either String a
readEither text = maybe (Left $ "Invalid parse: " ++ text) Right $ readMaybe text
--         default value ^         Wraps output on success ^

-- Same definition with different type signature and `readEither`
parseData :: String -> Either String [(Int, Int)]
parseData text = do
    values <- mapM (mapM readEither . words) . lines $ text
    mapM toPoint values

main = do
    points <- fmap parseData getContents
    case points of
        Right ps -> print $ meeting_point ps
        Left err -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ err
```

Comment: Thanks for for providing the cleaner code with error handling(which  provides a better how to handle errors). Since it is a contest problem (to get over the input file), i did just rewrote for now in shorter form which worked:<br>  xs <- fmap (map (read :: String -> Int) . concat . map (words) . lines) getContents<br> let points = f' xs<br> (f' [] = []<br>
f' (x:y:ys) = (x,y):f' ys)

Comment: @thayumanavar It's always good to write code to suit the problem at hand.  However, I would recommend writing `f` as `f (x:y:ys) = (x, y) : f ys; f _ = []`, to handle the case where the list has an odd number of elements, since you aren't handling the case `f [x]`.